# regular expression in hive

Tags: regex, hive, hiveql

I am learning simple regular expressions in Hive. I am following a tutorial and simple hql statements get an error?

```
select REGEXP_EXTRACT( 'Hello, my name is Ben. Please visit' , 'Ben' )
```

This is the error message I am getting:

`Wrong arguments ''Ben'': org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Unable to execute method public java.lang.String org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract.evaluate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) on object org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract@ec0c06f of class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.UDFRegExpExtract with arguments {Hello, my name is Ben. Please visit:java.lang.String, Ben:java.lang.String} of size 2`

It works in other languages, but I want to learn it in Hive. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `select REGEXP_EXTRACT( 'Hello, my name is Ben. Please visit' , 'Ben', 0)` work?

Comment: Yes it does thank you.

Comment: Once again thanks, I have upvoted. But cannot go more than 1 for some reason.

Comment: Once is enough :) Have a good day/night!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must provide the 3rd argument, the group index to extract.

To extract the full match, use `0`:

```
select REGEXP_EXTRACT( 'Hello, my name is Ben. Please visit' , 'Ben', 0)
```

To extract capturing group value, use the Group index, e.g.

```
select REGEXP_EXTRACT( 'Hello, my name is Ben. Please visit' , 'name is (\\w+)', 1)
```

will extract `Ben`.

See [this reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF):

> `regexp_extract(string subject, string pattern, int index)`
>   Returns the string extracted using the pattern. For example, `regexp_extract('foothebar', 'foo(.*?)(bar)', 2)` returns `'bar.'` Note that some care is necessary in using predefined character classes: using `'\s'` as the second argument will match the letter `s`; `'\\s'` is necessary to match whitespace, etc. The `'index'` parameter is the Java regex *Matcher* `group()` method index. See *docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html* for more information on the `'index'` or Java regex `group()` method.