# Hive regexp_extract: Extract category number if available

Tags: sql, regex, hive

I would like to find out whether my url contains category id or not. The category id in the url is always in the format **forward slash** + **category id of 1 up to 3 digits** + **dash** (for example **/228-** in https://www.google.com/search/228-bmw/location). For this purpose I have built a regexp_extract like this:

```
regexp_extract(url_string, '\/\d{1,3}-', 0)
```

Which works well in the editor I use for trials but query result is always just an empty string. Tried several modifications but either the result is the same or it throws an error. What could be wrong?

Comment: Have you already tried with the double backslash?

Comment: Use `regexp_extract(url_string, '/\\d{1,3}-', 0)`

Comment: try to use  regexp_extract(url_string,'(\/)([0-9]+)',2)

Comment: If you just need the number, yes, use a capturing group - `regexp_extract(url_string, '/(\\d{1,3})-', 1)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works indeed, thanks! But can you please explain? When I put this in the editor I use to check it shows no match (EditPad Pro 8). Maybe create full answer and I will approve it if you want?

Comment: All you need to understand is that *string literal* is not the same as a *literal string* or *plain text*. `'\s'` is an `s` because the backslash before an `s` is an invalid string escape sequence. The answer is already there, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46060773/3832970): "*Note that some care is necessary in using predefined character classes: using `'\s'` as the second argument will match the letter `s`; `'\\s'` is necessary to match whitespace, etc.*"